# Подключение к MySQL работает на локальном компьютере, но приложение не запускается на других ПК

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, xaml

Приложение написано на C#, для подключения использую библиотеку MySQL.Data.dll(v. 8.0.22) из MySql connector .NET&Mono. На локальном ПК проблем нет: приложение открывается и подключается к БД. Но при переносе .exe-файла на другой ПК(чтобы проверить возможность удалённого подключения) приложение просто не открывается и всё. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Надеюсь, код подключения к базе у вас не в конструкторе окна. Если в конструкторе, перенесите обязательно в обработчик события `Window.Loaded`.

Comment: Я так и использовала изначально, с конструкцией try-catch-finally, но проблема не в подключении к БД даже. Проблема в том,что программа не запускается на другом ПК (ну прям вообще никак, ни от имени админа, ни через cmd). Антивирусы тоже не причём, перед запуском все отключались. Просто не открывается программа на других ПК, только на моём. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема в исключении, я же написал вам в ответе. А вот где именно оно возникает - ищите. Покажите код приложения.

Comment: Надо не просто exe копировать, но и dll-ки, которые вы подключали к проекту на этапе разработки. А еще лучше создать инсталляционный пакет с помощью ClickOnce. Прав.клик по проекту -> Публиковать и далее сами разберетесь.

Comment: Вооот, спасибо. Создание инсталлятора для приложение помогло решить проблему, теперь всё прекрасно работает. Спасибо)